# MVC Web API in SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, sharepoint-2013

We're moving most of our web presence to our SharePoint server in the cloud. Our current setup uses a MVC Web API for data retrieval from DB. We do not want to host the API under a separate domain and thus need to move the API under SharePoint domain as well. There is no relaxation in this requirement.

Is there a way to publish my API to SharePoint? Or is there a SharePoint specific API project template in Visual Studio? If not what are my options?

**EDIT** Initially I have asked that MVC API needs to be part of the SharePoint 2013. But now things are such that API can reside anywhere - inside or outside - of SharePoint, as long as it is accessible from the root domain - which so far it seems not allowed (Error message:  **Calls to WebProxy without an app context are not allowed.**"). Still trying to see if this is possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: Do you own / control the sharepoint farm, or is it hosted at my-company.sharepoint.com ("in he cloud")?

Comment: @danludwig my-company.sharepoint.com (but does that mean i don't own-control the sp farm?)

Comment: You cannot publish a WebAPI to a sharepoint.com tenancy. Your unrelaxable requirement is simply not feasible. You can only use the app model as @IAfanasov mentions in his answer.

Comment: the requirement is actually based on avoiding the CORS route. another approach to satisfy this requirement (regardless of where API is hosted) can be creating a proxy page in SP that take a URL, sends to the API outside of SP and simply returns whatever the API replied. I tried following this idea but haven't found a way in to **create that proxy page that has code behind**. In VS 2013 there is an "App for Sharepoint" template (like @IAfanasov has mentioned), but that looks like a template for an user-interaction app. Tried adding Module and also Client Web Part but still no codebehind!

Comment: You don't use CORS in apps for sharepoint. You cannot write any code that runs on the SharePoint server. For SharePoint-hosted apps, you cannot write any server-side code at all. For Provider-hosted apps you can only write server-side code that runs in your provider web, using CSOM. It sounds like your solution might be a javascript-only one. There is an API that lets you get around the cross-domain issues by having server calls go through a proxy that is already hosted in sharepoint.com.

Comment: That's highly restrictive environment then. I wonder how people who need to move existing websites dependent on Web APIs and custom routes, like me, do it?

Comment: Yes it is restrictive, but there are good reasons for it, especially in sharepoint.com tenancies. Microsoft doesn't want your code running on machines that they have to support. You can implement as many custom routes as you want to, in your provider web, but it is not hosted on sharepoint.com. When you need to push/pull data to/from sharepoint, use CSOM or JSOM.

Comment: Sounds like we need to go CORS/JSONP route. We don't have a big team to manage a self-hosted SP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Use cloud SP as usual and issue JS API request (backed by CORS) whenever business data is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68664/discussion-between-danludwig-and-greatbear302).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the proxy you want to create is already part of SharePoint JSOM. Have a look at these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895(v=office.15).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245162(v=office.15).aspx

This will allow you to overcome cross origin issues. The `SP.WebProxy` and `SP.WebRequestInfo` allow you to use javascript to make a call outside of the domain where the javascript executes.

What really happens behind the scenes is that SharePoint's javascript API sends the request to your sharepoint.com tenancy server, which will then invoke the service from the SharePoint server, and return the response back to your javascript. You can implement it like so in a sharepoint-hosted app:

```
// this javascript executes from my-company.sharepoint.com
var responseDocument = undefined;
$('#cross').click(function () {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
    request.set_url('https://www.somewebapi.com/my/custom/route');
    request.set_method("GET");
    responseDocument = SP.WebProxy.invoke(ctx, request); // executes on sp server
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onError);
});
function onSuccess() {
    var response = responseDocument.get_body();
    alert('success ' + response);
}
function onError(err) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
}
```

...and since the remote api hosted at the other domain is called from the server, you don't have to worry about any of the cross-domain issues.

**Update**

To answer your update, please [check the results from this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Calls%20to%20WebProxy%20without%20an%20app%20context%20are%20not%20allowed.%22).

Have you added the remote endpoint to your AppManifest.xml?

Comment: **...sharepoint.com tenancy server...** - Cool! let me check into this!

Comment: The onSuccess callback alerted "Calls to WebProxy without an app context are not allowed."

Comment: @greatbear302 please click the OP comment to continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: @greatbear302 see my update. The above only works from a sharepoint app. In that app's AppManifest.xml, you need to add the remote endpoint of your API.

Comment: I've tried searching for that error (with quotes) and nothing useful comes out. I already added endpoint to appmanifest.xml, but then realized the SharePoint App model is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to find if I can do it from root domain itself (where is **it's** AppManifest.xml?). Last resort might be jsonp

Comment: I wonder if you could also just add a header to your WebAPI responses. Not sure what the WebAPI equivalent is off hand, but in MVC something like this works: `HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: API already allows CORS through various headers, it's the SP that needs an app context before it allows a call through it's proxy

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't give you a chance to define you own routes. Thats why you can not use old fashioned SharePoint solution to publish asp.net web api. You may consider using [apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930(v=office.15).aspx). It's like separate App with some connections to SharePoint.

Comment: If API is living outside of SP, how do I access it from root domain (not via an app)?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately switched to JSONP solution. Installed the [WebApiContrib.Formatting.JsonP](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp) in my MVC Web API project in Visual Studio, and modified SharePoint JavaScript, that calls the API, to include `?callback=?` (callback is equal to question mark). Everything stays the same. No SharePoint's proxy caller needed! No SharePoint app needed!